# Subsetting a dataframe in R by conditions for each column using a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R (lets call it "Animals") with columns named after animals like Rabbit, Cat, etc. It looks like this:

```
| Rabbit | Cat | Frog | Cow | Dog |
|--------|-----|------|-----|-----|
| 0      | 1   | 1    | 0   | 1   |
| 0      | 0   | 3    | 1   | 4   |
| 2      | 1   | 0    | 0   | 0   |
```

There are hundreds of rows in the list, and there are more animals (columns), too.

I want to take subsets of this dataframe for each animal where its number is greater than 0. For example, I want a subsetted Rabbits dataframe of only the rows in Animals where Rabbit > 0.

First I tried to create a variable "species":

```
species <- "Rabbit"
```

Then, I tried to subset the Animals data frame by using dplyr's filter():

```
Rabbits <- filter(Animals, species >= 1)
```

This didn't work because filter() was trying to look for a columned named "species" not "Rabbit".

I created the "species" variable because I hope to automate the process by looping through a vector of all my animal names and subsetting them into corressponding dataframes.

Is there a more efficient approach to this?

I'm very new to R so any ELI5 explanations would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a column by name using the `[]` syntax.

```
toKeep <- Alimals[species] >= 1
```

and then

```
Rabbit <- Animals[toKeep,]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! That's close to what I want, but the problem is I want to use a variable in place of Rabbit in Rabbit>=1. I.e. I want species>=1, where species <- "Rabbit". I want to use the species variable because this way I hope to look through all the animals. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: the other solution is to use the reshape2 package to transform your data, so that you have only two columns : one with the animal (rabbit, cat etc ... ) and the other the number of animals.

Comment: I'll also note that to programatically name the final dataframe as "Rabbit", I use assign(species, Animals[toKeep,])

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that creates a list of data.frames each subset by the columns passed in:

```
datasets <- lapply(colnames(mtcars), function(v) subset(mtcars, mtcars[,v] > 0))
```

Just change `colnames(mtcars)` to your species variable, and `mtcars` to your data.frame.

Comment: Thank you for this. To be honest I'm still really nervous about the apply family of functions, I can never figure out which one to use or how. Will need to work on this more.

Comment: It's worth learning! They are safe functions to use and experiment with. lapply works well on lists (which data.frames are). I think it's a much safer way then using `assign`.

Comment: Thanks @Zelazny7 ! I'll go look for some good ELI5 intros to those functions, and maybe try to find some tutorials with exercises on them.